# python selenium error message.(Windows WebAuthn API failed to load)

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I can't figure out. where is the problem occur. chrome driver? or vscode?

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
PS F:\python workspace>  & 'C:\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\오우예아\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '7200' '--' 'f:\python workspace\nado_crawl\20OHLC(완성).py'

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7210/devtools/browser/d4efe470-5339-4f9b-95c7-c09f1a227575
[5232:7696:0519/201224.325:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:12:24.331] FIDO: webauthn_api.cc:54 Windows WebAuthn API failed to load
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm glad you asked this.

Comment: Facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with VSCode, I ran my web **scraper** on visual studio 2019 and it is working with chrome  Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and driver version: ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19